# Vuejs v-for in option element for select input. Get the value from JSON object, and use it in option value

Tags: html, vue.js, input, html-select

```
<option v-for="{Service, Price} in delivery_array">
    {{Service}} - Rp {{Price}}
</option>
```

that's my option list from delivery_array

My delivery_array value:

```
[
    {"Price": "18000", "Service": "REG"},
    {"Price": "30000", "Service": "FAS"}
]
```

I want to add value attribute in every option element with JSON object like this:

```
{"Price": "THE_PRICE", "Service": "THE_SERVICE"}
```

So it looked like this:

```
<option v-for="{Service, Price} in delivery_array" value='{"service":{{Service}}, "price":{{Price}} }'>
    {{Service}} - Rp {{Price}}
</option>
```

But I have no idea how to code it like that.

I try it before with v-model attribute like `v-model="Service"`, and I get the error message like this:

> : v-model is not supported on this element type. If you are working with `contenteditable`, it's recommended to wrap a library dedicated for that purpose inside a custom component.

If I have a missing information or bad grammar in my question. I will edit it. Sorry for my bad english language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `v-model` should be in select element and the `value` in option :

```
<select v-model="delivery">
<option v-for="{Service, Price} in delivery_array" :value='{"service":Service, "price":Price }'>
    {{Service}} - Rp {{Price}}
</option>

</select>
```

`delivery` must be declared as data property, and value bound like  `:value='...`

Comment: Sorry, I need help again. The value become Like this: [object Object]
How to get the object value from it? I use PHP on my backend.

Answer (score 2):

The `v-model` goes on the `select` tag, since that holds the value for the selected option. You also need a `key` on the `v-for`.

I don't know if you can use destructuring in the `v-for` directly, but this should work:

```
<select v-model="Service">
    <option v-for="item in delivery_array" :value="item.Service" :key="item.Service">
        {{ item.Service }} - Rp {{ item.Price }}
    </option>
</select>
```

Comment: You could use destructing in `v-for`